# how to pick and place object with Moveit and Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, moveit, ros-melodic, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a robot is controlled thought MoveIt! ,but now i don't know how to integrate with Kinect in order to object detection and pick, place. I read about PCL, tabletop_object, but still don't have the best solution.
Can you suggest me? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345100/how-to-pick-and-place-object-with-moveit-and-kinect/) by [bkmen97](https://answers.ros.org/users/37120/bkmen97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

[Find_object_2d package](http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d) is a great way to get into object detection and pick-and-place pipelines. Basically using a find_object_3d node to subscribe to `/color` and `/depth` topics and publishing detected objects' properties (such as id, width and length) to `/objects` topic. The UI is pretty simple and straightforward, you just take a snapshot of the image and make a bounding box for the object in the frame.

The best thing? The node also publishes object coordinate transformation and rotation using `tf`. You can look up the transformation from the object frame to camera frame and base frame and plan your pipeline from there.

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [SSar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50955/ssar/) with karma: 53 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bkmen97](https://answers.ros.org/users/37120/bkmen97/) on 2020-02-26**:
thanks for your suggestion, i trying to use Find_object_2d package

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-02-29**:
Please accept the answer if it solved your problem